# Include stylesheet in different mode

Tags: angular

I want to include different stylesheet for differents mode (dev, prod ...).
what is the best way to do this ?
I just want to add a steelsheet for dev mode.

I use angular 6 and I don't use webpack.

Comment: You will use the same stylesheet for dev and prod. Not sure why you want two different stylesheets.

Comment: Do you mean for one component, or global stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

normally including a stylesheet for production only is a very bad idea, since you dont test it for errors, but im sure you have your reasons.

To include a prod stylesheet as it were, you can always add it as a prod only dependancy in the package.json, I guess

Comment: If is a bad idea, what is the best idea to add some css just in production ?

Comment: the bad is adding the css just in production, not my method. Unless you are confident the css stylesheet will have no problems, like bootstrap or foundation or reset.